# Bound TypeVar on generic methods inside generic class

Tags: python-3.x, generics, typing, type-variables

For some reason, this code lints up as a problem:

```
from typing import *
T = TypeVar("T", bound="Foo")
S = TypeVar("S")

class Foo(Generic[S]):
    @classmethod
    def func(cls: Type[T]) -> T:
        return cls()
```

Mypy linter sends me to the `def func` line, saying `Unsupported type Type["T"]`. This does not happen if `Foo` is not defined as a generic class.

Is this a bug? What am I doing wrong?

I'm using `S` for different methods, and I wish to use `T` and `Type[T]` later on inside subclasses of `Foo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is a [bug in mypy](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3631). Unfortunately, the best workaround for now is to just add a `# type: ignore` annotation to that line, perhaps along with a link to the relevant issue. Later, you can check if that warning has been fixed by running mypy with the `--warn-unused-ignores` flag.

Comment: Apart from remembering all of mypy's issues, how do you find if things like this are a bug or not? Searching github isn't always easy for these issues.

Comment: @Bharel -- In general, mypy's type system is designed to be relatively straightforward. Of course, there are a few gotchas here and there, but if something feels like a bug, it usually is. (The second most common scenario is that you're looking for a feature that hasn't been implemented yet.)

Comment: In this case, I read your snippet and agreed the error made no sense. I then found the relevant issue by searching "typevar classmethod" -- that narrowed down the number of issues to about. The reason I tacked on the keyword "classmethod" was because I happened to know that mypy currently struggles a little when working with decorators. You used a classmethod in your snippet, so I suspected that was likely partially the culprit. (If I were less lazy, I would have also tried repro-ing your issue after removing the `@classmethod` to confirm my hunch.)

Comment: More broadly, you can try just asking on the gitter or filing an issue -- that's what I do when I'm not sure if something's a bug/if I can't find an open issue. Of course, sometimes I'm wrong and the code is fine/I missed the issue, but no biggie, mistakes happen. The mypy core devs encourage people to ask questions using the issue tracker anyways.

Comment: Thank you very much for the extended explanation! You're awesome!